# Programmatically open and close Chart.js tooltip

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

`Chart.js 2.2.1`

Any idea how to trigger the code that runs when I hover over a datapoint, and that runs when I move the mouse off?  I need to programmatically show and hide a chart's tooltip.

```
openTip(oChart, datasetIndex, pointIndex){
   // how to open a specific tooltip?
}
closeTip(oChart, datasetIndex, pointIndex){
   // how to close the same tooltip?
}
```

I would show sample code if I could, but I don't even know where to start. The [chart method docs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#advanced-usage-prototype-methods) haven't helped.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ucvvvnm4/3/)

Comment: I don't have time to solution this as code but in your fiddle, maybe you could create a mouseover event and trigger it with the pageX and pageY coordinates of the bar's tooltip you'd like to see. Essentially simulating a mouseover event for the bar's tooltip you'd like to see. I'm not sure how you could swap datasets though. You'll probably have to call the update method on the chart element. I'll revisit this tomorrow. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: @gautsch appreciate the suggestion. Was hoping for a solution that plugs into the chart's properties and methods directly. Take a look at Raghav's answer below

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The code below will handle one or more tooltips.

```
function openTip(oChart,datasetIndex,pointIndex){
   if(window.oChart.tooltip._active == undefined)
      window.oChart.tooltip._active = []
   var activeElements = window.oChart.tooltip._active;
   var requestedElem = window.oChart.getDatasetMeta(datasetIndex).data[pointIndex];
   for(var i = 0; i < activeElements.length; i++) {
       if(requestedElem._index == activeElements[i]._index)  
          return;
   }
   activeElements.push(requestedElem);
   //window.oChart.tooltip._view.body = window.oChart.getDatasetMeta(datasetIndex).data;
   window.oChart.tooltip._active = activeElements;
   window.oChart.tooltip.update(true);
   window.oChart.draw();
}

function closeTip(oChart,datasetIndex,pointIndex){
   var activeElements = window.oChart.tooltip._active;
   if(activeElements == undefined || activeElements.length == 0)
     return;
   var requestedElem = window.oChart.getDatasetMeta(datasetIndex).data[pointIndex];
   for(var i = 0; i < activeElements.length; i++) {
       if(requestedElem._index == activeElements[i]._index)  {
          activeElements.splice(i, 1);
          break;
       }
   }
   window.oChart.tooltip._active = activeElements;
   window.oChart.tooltip.update(true);
   window.oChart.draw();
}
```

Complete solution provided by @BeetleJuice - https://jsfiddle.net/ucvvvnm4/5/

Comment: My goodness Raghav I don't think I could have gotten there on my own. Thanks a ton.  If you think it's a good idea, feel free to add this updated JSFiddle to your answer: https://jsfiddle.net/ucvvvnm4/5/ . *<bear hug>*

Comment: For developer doing some kind of snapshot (to url image, or toBlob), don't forget to resize before adding the tooltips. (Just saying) Thank's for your answer @raghav-tandon

Comment: The solution provided does not even compile

Answer (score 27):

I would be careful accessing/modifying private variables that begin with `_`. You may find yourself with unexpected behavior. Why not trigger the canvas `mousemove` event

```
  function openToolTip (myChart, index) {

    var mouseMoveEvent, meta, point, rectangle, value;

    meta = myChart.getDatasetMeta(index);
    rectangle = myChart.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    point = meta.data[0].getCenterPoint();

    mouseMoveEvent = new MouseEvent('mousemove', {
      clientX: rectangle.left + point.x,
      clientY: rectangle.top + point.y
    });
    
    myChart.canvas.dispatchEvent(mouseMoveEvent);

  },
```

To close the tooltip just trigger the `mouseout` event

```
  function closeToolTip (myChart) {

    var mouseOutEvent = new MouseEvent('mouseout');
    return myChart.canvas.dispatchEvent(mouseOutEvent);

  }
```

Comment: Smart solution.

Comment: Nice one. This helped me out of jam where we needed keyboard-only users to be able to see the tooltips on demand.

Comment: much better than accepted answer, this should be accepted!

Comment: This code crashed on indices > 0 for me, I edited the answer to put the index in the call to getDatasetMeta() and dereference meta.data[0] instead of meta.data[index] - this worked for me in practice with ChartJS 3.

Answer (score 1):

For **Chart.js@3** here's official solution: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/advanced/programmatic-events.html

```js
function triggerTooltip(chart) {
  const tooltip = chart.tooltip;
  if (tooltip.getActiveElements().length > 0) {
    tooltip.setActiveElements([], {x: 0, y: 0});
  } else {
    const chartArea = chart.chartArea;
    tooltip.setActiveElements([
      {
        datasetIndex: 0,
        index: 2,
      }, {
        datasetIndex: 1,
        index: 2,
      }
    ],
    {
      x: (chartArea.left + chartArea.right) / 2,
      y: (chartArea.top + chartArea.bottom) / 2,
    });
  }

  chart.update();
}
```

Comment: Could you please fix the link? Currently it is self-referencing one.